# LinkedIn SDK duplicate symbol

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, cocoapods

I downloaded latest LinkedIn SDK and added to my project but building failed

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PodsDummy_Pods in:
>       /linkedin-sdk.framework/linkedin-sdk(Pods-dummy.o)
>       /Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(Pods-dummy.o) duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_PodsDummy_Pods in:
>       /linkedin-sdk.framework/linkedin-sdk(Pods-dummy.o)
>       /Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(Pods-dummy.o) ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent duplicate symbols when building static library with Cocoapods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249273/prevent-duplicate-symbols-when-building-static-library-with-cocoapods)

Comment: Also here is discussion of this issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1767

Comment: This solution solved the same problem for me: 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/30722343/3820161

Comment: @dce do you mean that I should rename all symbols of pod libraries to solve problem. I guess LinkedIn developers should fix it

Comment: yeah +1 for @Rinat comment. Why should I change all of my other pods. Such a bad bug for a very late coming library. Haven't they test this case?

Comment: @keremkeskin do you know how to report bug to LinkedIn developers? I couldn't find

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same issue, and found a workaround until the LinkedIn SDK is 'fixed'.

Simply update the Pods-dummy.m file in the Pods Xcode project from:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface PodsDummy_Pods : NSObject
@end
@implementation PodsDummy_Pods
@end
```

to

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface PodsDummy_Podsxx : NSObject
@end
@implementation PodsDummy_Podsxx
@end
```

and it will then link.

Note: you will need to patch this each time you update your Pods via the command line, e.g. "pod install" or update etc.

Comment: This is awesome.. simple fix and it worked like a charm...Thanks dude..!!

Comment: @Peter Li, Amazing hack dude! :)

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment so I will leave this as a reply to @rinat , I didn't need to change the other pods name, just add:

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] =     '$(inherited), PodsDummy_Pods=SomeOtherNamePodsDummy_Pods'
        end
    end
end
```

to the pod file. Anyways the SDK linkedIn didn't work at all for me. I haven't been able to make it work, it simply doesn't work when authenticating with the app ready. No logs, nothing... I ended implementing a normal OAuth2 web login.

Answer (score 3):

Hey no need to change **PodsDummy_Pods** name to **PodsDummy_Podsxx**  each time you update your Pods via the command line, e.g. "pod install" or update etc.

Paste below code in Podfile. linkedIn SDK working cool......

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] = '$(inherited), PodsDummy_Pods=SomeOtherNamePodsDummy_Pods'
        end
    end
end
```