# iOS framework build fail 'include of non-modular header inside framework module'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I'm working on 'Cocoa Touch Framework' project in Xcode 7.2.
It installs 'AFNetworking' via cocoapods.

MyFramework.h (public),

```
#import <MyFramework/MyTest.h>
```

MyTest.h (public),

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
...
```

And I have another 'MyProject' project that uses the MyFramework.framework.
It also pods AFNetworking.

AppDelegate.m,

```
#import <MyFramework/MyFramework.h>
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
...
```

When I build 'MyProject', 'include of non-modular header inside framework module' error appears. I set **Allow Non-modular includes in Frame Modules** to **YES** but it is not the solution I want since it is a temporary solution that produces ambiguous reference errors in the future.

I have tried pod's '[post_install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605504/xcode-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-error-after-updating-cocoa-pods)' and '[prefix](http://blog.sigmapoint.pl/avoiding-dependency-collisions-in-ios-static-library-managed-by-cocoapods/)' method but it doesn't work.
I think the 'prefix' thing is no more working because pod's build process is something changed..

Can anyone help? Any suggestions would be great for me.