# Duplicate symbols with Audiokit pod

Tags: swift, xcode, chirp

I'm getting the error "36 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64".

They all seem to involve a conflict with the audiokit pod. Below is one of the 36:

```
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_EZAudioDevice' in:
    /Users/oliversilverstein/Desktop/Github/LieFinderIOS/Pods/AudioKit/iOS/AudioKit.framework/AudioKit(EZAudioDevice.o)
    /Users/oliversilverstein/Desktop/Github/LieFinderIOS/Pods/ChirpSDK/ChirpSDK.framework/ChirpSDK(EZAudioDevice.o)
```

Any potential fix or this an issue on your end?

I've already tried almost every solution suggested by googling. Thanks!

Comment: From project navigation in bottom "Filter" type " 2" or " 3". Are there files with these names?

Comment: Hi, I don't see any

Comment: I had it, the reason was cocoapod. He created duplicates of several files. For all the occasions try "pod deintegrate" -> "pod clean" -> "pod install". Maybe this will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

This error suggests that the Chirp SDK also includes the EZAudio library. Can you use something like in this answer to rename the symbols?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32605678/5585515