# Swift Preprocessing Error: Expected end of line in preprocessor expression

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods, leveldb

Okay so I was solving an issue regarding [duplicate symbols in cocoa pods' architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605504/xcode-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-error-after-updating-cocoa-pods). After getting the pods installed with the `post_install` in the accepted solution, I build my xcworkspace project and I run into the following error:

[Screenshot of location of file and error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us5Wa.png)

The error is: Expected end of line in preprocessor expression.
On the line: `#if HAVE_FULLFSYNC`
In the method: `SyncFd(int fd, const std::string& fd_path)`
And the location of the file is: Pods/Pods/leveldb-library/env_posix.cc

The Pod I added which started this series of issues is 'CodableFirebase' from [here](https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase).

And this is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '13.2'

post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] = '$(inherited), PodsDummy_Pods=SomeOtherNamePodsDummy_Pods'
        end
    end
end


target 'ShoeSwiperMenus' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ShoeSwiperMenus
# add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
# add pods for any other desired Firebase products
# https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod ‘FirebaseUI/Auth'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
pod 'FirebaseUI'
pod 'MaterialComponents/Buttons'
pod 'MaterialComponents/Buttons+Theming'
# pod 'MaterialComponents/schemes/Color'

pod 'Shuffle-iOS'
pod 'JGProgressHUD'
pod 'LBTATools'
pod 'CodableFirebase'

end
```

When removing the `post_install` block, I backtrack onto my original error which is:
ld: 202 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64.
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm really out of my depth here... I don't even know how to start solving this (nothing on Google). Please help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. In this case, at least provide your Podfile.

Comment: Not sure how to make the question more complete or reproducible... I don't know what triggers the error in the first place

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I suspect you were running into similar problems that I am getting now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855053/swift-package-manager-spm-and-cocoapod-dependency-conflict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added your Podfile to an empty project, got the same errors, then removed the `post_install` block and was able to build without errors.

So, remove the `post_install` block. Whatever problem it supposedly solves, it creates this one.

Also, I would recommend adding `inhibit_all_warnings!` to the Podfile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comments Gereon! I unfortunately need the `post_install` block. Its purpose is to remove duplicate symbols in the architecture (as explained [here](https://developerinsider.co/cocoapods-remove-duplicate-symbols-errors/)). It prevents another error I was getting when installing the CodableFirebase pod

Comment: Ah, `inhibit_all_warnings!`, this is a great help!

Comment: So I tried sparing the `leveldb-library` from the `post_install` block, but that didn't help

Comment: Like I said, there are no error in my project. It's also no surprise that you don't see any linker errors when the compilation step fails.

Comment: I do see a linker error when removing the `post_install` block though... I added it at the bottom of the question. I'm really confused as to how you can build this without any errors. Is there anything else that could make it crash on my end?

Comment: Check your project's "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content" section. Is there anything listed there except your pods framework, and in particular, anything that duplicates something from your pods?