# duplicate symbol in Pods

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, frameworks, cocoapods

I have a Podfile and I installed my frameworks from there. Now, I need to add one framework manually, to my project and on adding it gives me the next error:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_PodsDummy_Pods in:    
my_project_path/Appodeal.framework/Appodeal(Pods-dummy.o)
/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-app-bamupbgzptvzbygckzrxausporaj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods.framework/Pods(Pods-dummy.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PodsDummy_Pods in:

my_project_path/Appodeal.framework/Appodeal(Pods-dummy.o)
/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My-app-bamupbgzptvzbygckzrxausporaj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods.framework/Pods(Pods-dummy.o)

ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

After adding it I cannot compile my project because of this error. How can fix this error?

My Podfile looks like:

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'RealmSwift'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is a common error and happens when 2 same files clash.

Firstly, try this: go to Window > Projects > (Click on your project) > Delete (Derived Data).

If this doesn't work, you will have to manually delete one of the copies of the clashing file.

Check these out. They explain perfectly what to do:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1729
[Prevent duplicate symbols when building static library with Cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249273/prevent-duplicate-symbols-when-building-static-library-with-cocoapods)[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249273/prevent-duplicate-symbols-when-building-static-library-with-cocoapods)